# Angular controller inheritance with view routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular app, and I am currently using `$routeProvider` to route the urls to a template with an `ng-view` directive:

**app.js**

```
.config( function ($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/project/:projectId', {
        // this is the partial...
        templateUrl : 'partials/_project_detail.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            project: function ($route, MyService) {
                return MyService.get('projects/', $route.current.params.projectId);
        }
    })
})

.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function ($scope, project) {
    ...
    $scope.project = project;
})
```

**index.html**

```
...
<div ng-view></div>
...
```

Now, I would like to use controller scope inheritance to have a child controller within the parent one, along the lines of:

**project_detail.tmpl.html**

```
...
<h2>Project: {{ project.title }}</h2> <!-- this works -->

<div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
   <h2>Project: {{ project.title }}</h2> <!-- this doesn't work -->
</div>
...
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I know according to the Angular docs that you can inherit scope between parent and child scopes if both controllers are declared in the template: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Is there some way to achieve inheritance using the router method?

Comment: Try $rootScope.project = project;

Comment: Hmm. That kind of defeats the object of scope inheritance. If I bind to `$rootScope`, then the child controller doesn't need to be nested, it could just be anywhere. I would rather keep the scope objects to just these two controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you are binding to primitive value, instead of an object in your controller. Try using an object with dot notation, for example: {{ project.var1 }}

If this is the problem, I recommend you watching this video: [Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)

Comment: Actually `$scope.project` is an object, I should have been more explicit in my template code. I have edited it now. The title property is available in the Parent controller but not in the Child.

Comment: Have you created the ChildCtrl in your .js file? I have recreated your problem, with injecting, as you did, and it works fine. Maybe you can show us what is inside MyService?

Comment: Yes, the controller is definitely instantiated, and the Child should inherit the project object from the scope not the service. Also the project object is correct before the controller directive in the template.

Comment: I have started a plunker, which might help to see what is happening: http://plnkr.co/edit/rUdPBzbHX0bGOwtjQEIt?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker is broken, I've created another one which is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/LclNy5UUWINcJ33svDPi?p=preview

Comment: Ha!  Great. Well, you have proved that it works great. I will investigate what the problem is in my code.

Comment: Right. So the issue was that the `ChildCtrl` had dependencies in there which were unnecessary, in fact for straight up inheritance it should be empty. e.g. `.controller('InfoCtrl', function () {})`.

Comment: That is interesting, I've forked my plunkr, but I don't know if this is what you have ment. http://plnkr.co/edit/9rT75ZappKXNCltVnIx4?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, there must have been a bug with one of the dependencies - I had copied them all from the parent controller just in case. Not sure which one was throwing the error.